# Hide 'Sync' button but allow 'Add shortcut to OneDrive' in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to allow people to add a shortcut, from a document library in SharePoint, to their OneDrive and hide the 'Sync' button in SharePoint.

[image]

This is what I have tried:

In the tenant settings https://[tenantname]-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx I'm hiding the sync button.

[image]

But the sync button keeps showing in SharePoint.

[image]

The only way I can hide the sync button is to set 'Offline Client Availability' in advanced list settings to No.

[image]

When I do that the 'Sync' button is hidden and I can still see the 'Add shortcut to OneDrive' button - great this is what I want. When I click on 'Add shortcut to OneDrive' the shortcut is added to OneDrive but it has a red cross and I can't browse the files because 'Offline Client Availability' is turned off.

[image]

This is what I would like:

- Hide 'Sync' button
- Show 'Add shortcut to OneDrive'
- For the added shortcut folder in OneDrive to show the files from SharePoint

How would I achieve this? And has anyone else been able to hide the sync button from the tenant settings? I know this change can take a little time to take effect but I have waited for 20 hours and it still didn't work. Is there a bug?

Comment: As of 12 Sep 2023 this is still an issue.